# Why is this code being run more than once on each click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, recursion

Having a hard time figuring out why this alert code is being called once on 1st click, twice on 2nd click, four times on 3rd click, eight times on 4th click, etc...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#preventClickDiv a[href]').click(function(e){ 
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('Prevented');
        newClick();
    });
});
function newClick(){
    $('#preventClickDiv a[href]').click(function(e){ 
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('Prevented');
        newClick();
    });
}
```

Comment: What's the reason for `newClick()`? Just remove it completely.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first block creates a click event that calls `newClick` which creates a click event that calls itself... which creates another event... I think you get the idea. Take out the click event binding code in the function.

It should just be something like:

```
function newClick(){
    alert("in new click");
}
```

Comment: Sorry, that was a horribly worded question. I was running into a problem where instead of calling for an alert I was running some ajax which returned a new set of links which weren't responding to the clicks prevent default. I found the jquery's .live feature and this has solved my problem. Sorry again!

Comment: No worries. However, the `.live()` method is deprecated (as of 1.7). You should use [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) instead.

Answer (score 1):

You are binding a click event inside of a click event, so for every time you click, you bind another click event, resulting in a very large number of click events being bound to the same element(s) multiple times on each click.

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is registering an *additional* click handler every time `newClick()` is called, not replacing the old one – it doesn't go away just because the event fired. Just do this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#preventClickDiv a[href]').click(function(e){ 
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('Prevented');
    });
});
```

(Also, preventing users from clicking on links is a good way to generate hate.)